# can't find source for layer 'mapbox-location-layer'

Tags: android, location, mapbox

I am using mapbox to display map in android. I want t display user's current location. When I am running the program in emulator with API 23, it is running fine and I am able too see current location. But when I am running same program on an Android device, I am getting the warning as follow:

```
{GLThread 597}[Render]: can't find source for layer 'mapbox-location-shadow'
{GLThread 597}[Render]: can't find source for layer 'mapbox-location-stroke-layer'
{GLThread 597}[Render]: can't find source for layer 'mapbox-location-layer'
```

Also, I am not able to see current location.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been reported many times in the past week and we have a fix that's waiting for review, once merged we'll release 0.5.1 which will contain the fix to the issue you are speaking about.

Comment: Do you have a timeline when it will be released?
Or it there a workaround to get it working without this new version.

Comment: Thank you. Can please tell when it will be released?

Comment: According to maven central the fixes version is already published, I had not time to check it out.
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mapbox.mapboxsdk/mapbox-android-plugin-locationlayer